# insert video into a playlist with youtube api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Hey so I am fairly familiar to the youtube api .. I know how to read channels and playlist along with getting any relevant video information I identify as Important 
I'm using php to do all of this but in order to make sure I have the correct idea of how each request/response works I attempted it in the browser with the API explorer

Now I am trying to insert videos into a playlist I just created (also through the API) but I am having some trouble figuring out exactly how my request is not properly formed

Here's The request

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_WT2TRZzH1t86nVlX26z9WPp-gnDTxVHGvdQ6xx0vyTzmkYeXkLdJerwllLzF_a
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
  "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "PL8hD12HFC-nuswc21_e64aPAy9B25sEH7",
    "resourceId": {
      "videoId": "KMGuyGY5gvY"
    }
  }
}
```

here is the response

```
400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
     "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
     "reason": "invalidResourceType",
     "message": "Resource type not supported."
   }
  ],
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Resource type not supported."
 }
}
```

the playlist is an empty publicly viewable playlist I created using the API Explorer and is viewable through standard youtube website.
The video is randomly selected off of youtube ... tried a few as thought it might be a specific problem with a video but no luck .. I have switched on OAuth and am using an account that is a verified youtube partner

However I can seemed to figure out why the resource type is not supported I've looked around the web along with answers to the left without finding exactly what I am doing wrong.. any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated
 as I am kind of stuck at the moment

Comment: Where do you get an API key?

Comment: right here https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your `resourceId` isn't complete, as it doesn't identify to the API how to interpret the `videoId` parameter. Try setting the `kind` attribute of the `resourceId`, like this:

```
  "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "PL8hD12HFC-nuswc21_e64aPAy9B25sEH7",
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "KMGuyGY5gvY"
    }
  }
```

That way, the API will know in which 'domain' (so to speak) to locate the resource identified by the string you send in.

Comment: Awesome thanks .. if I need to define a kind as youtube#video what other kinds are acceptable as I assumed a youtube video would be only thing that could be added to a playlist?

Answer (score 3):

this will help constructing resourceID

```
def add_video_to_playlist(videoID,playlistID):
    youtube = get_authenticated_service() #write it yourself
    add_video_request=youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
                'snippet': {
                  'playlistId': playlistID, 
                  'resourceId': {
                          'kind': 'youtube#video',
                      'videoId': videoID
                    }
                #'position': 0
                }
        }
    ).execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

Read documentation at [Youtube Data Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/)

```
    $playlistId = 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID_STARTS_WITH_PL';
    $resourceId = new Google_Service_YouTube_ResourceId();
    $resourceId->setVideoId('REPLACE_WITH_VIDEO_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD');
    $resourceId->setKind('youtube#video');


    $playlistItemSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItemSnippet();
    $playlistItemSnippet->setTitle('YOUR_VIDEO_TITLE');
    $playlistItemSnippet->setPlaylistId($playlistId);
    $playlistItemSnippet->setResourceId($resourceId);


    $playlistItem = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem();
    $playlistItem->setSnippet($playlistItemSnippet);
    $playlistItemResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->insert(
        'snippet,contentDetails', $playlistItem, array());</i>
```

Full project is available at my [GitHub](https://github.com/iamnaran/utubePlaylist)

Comment: More relevant link specifically for Playlistitems: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems