# inserting videos to a youtube playlist with python apiclient

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to add a youtube video to a public youtube playlist, but I keep getting 403 responses with the reason "playlistItemsNotAccessible":

```
import googleapiclient
import httplib2
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
             'secrets.json', scopes)

youtube_admin = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

try:
    playlist_insert_response = youtube_admin.playlistItems().insert(
    part="snippet",
    body={
        'snippet': {
            'playlistId': '<playlist id>',
            'resourceId': {
                'kind': 'youtube#video',
                'videoId': '<video id>'
            },
            'position': 0
        }
    }
).execute()

except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as err:
    print(vars(err))
```

Help anyone?

Comment: Try [inserting a video on YOUR own playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) first. If it works, then the issue here is you have no authorization to access the public playlist.

Comment: That's what I tried to do from the first place...

Comment: did it work on your own playlist?

Comment: nope
(bla bla - comments have to be 15 chars min)

Comment: Try this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650415/insert-video-into-a-playlist-with-youtube-api-v3), you seem to have similar use case.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue. The problem in the thread you attached is that the 'kind': 'youtube#video' attribute was missing in request body, while I have it in my request. Please assume that I read already every possibly-related stack-overflow thread.

Comment: In case other users stumped upon this thread first, check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228815/adding-youtube-video-to-playlist-using-python) for reference.